# Finding the exact value of $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos \frac{2}{5}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos \frac{2}{5}\right)$$
>   How do we evaluate this by using trigonometric identity?
>
> The options are $\dfrac{\sqrt{24}}{1}$, $\dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{7}$, $\dfrac{\sqrt{70}}{10}$, $\dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}$, $\dfrac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$.

I know that

$$\arccos \frac {2}{5} \neq \cos \frac {2}{5}$$

However, I don't have any idea about how to.

Comment: $\arccos\frac{2}{5}=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$ is definitely different from $\cos\frac{2}{5}$: $$ \arccos\frac{2}{5}\geq \frac{\pi}{3}> 1 \geq \cos\frac{2}{5}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, that was really a big mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$\tan\frac A2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos A}{1+\cos A}}$$ so $$\tan\left(\frac12\arccos\frac25\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-2/5}{1+2/5}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac37}$$

Note that as $0<\arccos\dfrac25<\dfrac\pi2$ the positive root is taken so $$\boxed{\tan\left(\frac12\arccos\frac25\right)=\sqrt{\frac37}}$$

Comment: According to my textbook, it seems wrong.

Comment: According to my calculator, it seems right.

Comment: But why it says that this is incorrect?

Comment: @Goendo Can't your textbook be wrong?

Comment: @Botond There are five option.

Comment: +1. Note that $\operatorname{arccos}(2/5)$ is in the first quadrant, so the tangent is unambiguously positive.

Comment: @Goendo Why then don't you write down the options your book gives in your question?

Comment: $$\frac {\sqrt 24}{1} , \frac {\sqrt 21}{7}, \frac {\sqrt 70}{10}, \frac {2\sqrt 5}{5}, \frac {3\sqrt 10}{10}$$

Comment: @Blue Thanks. Added!

Comment: @Goendo Note that $$\frac{\sqrt{21}}7=\frac{\sqrt7\sqrt3}7=\sqrt{\frac37}$$ as I have written.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I'm too sorry for that! :) Also wondered how you did calculations via calculator?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire How did you calculate it by calculator?

Comment: Step $1$: switch to radian mode. Step $2$: input the expression in. Step $3$: square the value and multiply it by $7$. You should get $3$ in the end.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire What do you mean by input the values in?

Comment: The expression: $\tan(0.5\cos^{-1}(0.4))$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why that expression?

Comment: Because that is the expression you want!!!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It was $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos \frac{2}{5}\right)$ lol

Comment: But isn't $\dfrac12=0.5$ and $\dfrac25=0.4$? I wrote the decimal expansions just to save time but either way should work on your calculator.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Awesome! and why $\cos^{-1}$?

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter (though this form is usually more common). The inverse cosine button on your calculator should have one of them.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire but with the calculator, it's impossible to get step by step lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73960/discussion-between-thesimplifire-and-goendo).

Answer (score 8):

By the bisector theorem, it is $\frac{1}{7}\sqrt{21}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}$:

[image]

More generally, for any $r\in[0,1]$ we have
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos r\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-r}{1+r}}. $$

Comment: (+1) Nice way to prove the identity that $$\tan\frac A2=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos A}{1+\cos A}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos \frac{2}{5}\right)= \tan(x) $$ Where $$ x=\frac{1}{2}\arccos \frac{2}{5}$$ Thus $$2x = \arccos\frac25$$ Which implies $$\cos(2x)=\frac25$$  Note that $$\cos(2x)= 1-2\sin^2(x)=\frac25 \implies \sin^2(x)=\frac3{10}$$

Thus $\cos^2(x)=\frac7{10}$ and $\tan^2(x) = \frac37.$

That implies that $$\tan(x)= \sqrt {\frac37}=.6546536707.$$